# How to implement two-factor authentication in CAS server

Tags: cas

How to implement two-factor authentication in CAS server.

Want to know How to implement two-factor authentication in CAS server. Preferred google-authenticator

Comment: Have you checked [official documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuring-Multifactor-Authentication.html)? There is also a [google-authenticator](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/GoogleAuthenticator-Authentication.html) section. I suggest to follow the docs and ask a specific question. You question as it is now, is too broad.

Comment: Yes. I checked. But don't have an idea how to execute those steps. I know add dependency and config. But don't know how to build again and apply changes.

Comment: Just follow the [documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/planning/Installation-Requirements.html#). Instructions on how to build are available on [github](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template).

Comment: Hey. thank you.I will try